# gulp ignore doesn't remove first slash

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, inject

I am creating Gulp task that will inject js and css using wiredep. below is how it is getting injected.

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="/public/js/config/app.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/components/home-component.js"></script>
```

but I need to inject

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="public/js/config/app.js"></script>
<script src="public/js/components/home-component.js"></script>
```

I managed to replace `../` to ``

How do I Ignore first `'/'`?

This is what I have tried and didn't work.

Gulp task is below

```
gulp.task('index', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('./public/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src(config.appjs.concat(config.appcss), {read: false});

    return target.pipe(inject(sources))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            ignorePath: "../"
        }))
        // .pipe(wiredep({
        //     ignorePath: "/"
        // }))
        // .pipe(wiredep({
        //     ignorePath: "/(.*?)\\/"
        // }))

        // .pipe(wiredep(
        //     {
        //         fileTypes: {
        //             html: {
        //                 replace: {
        //                     js: '<script src="{{filePath}}"></script>',
        //                     css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}">'
        //                 }
        //             }
        //         }
        //     }))

        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

and

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('./public/js/**/*.js')
            .pipe(wiredep({
                ignorePath: '/',
                addRootSlash: false
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/public/js'));
});
```